# ¿Cómo importar datos desde Excel usando gema 'roo'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Estoy siguiendo [este tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_NSBm_Q431Y&t=487s) de *Railscasts*  en importación de registros usando un archivo de Excel usando la gema *roo*. El importar y exportar data funcionan bien pero al momento de importar datos relacionados, me muestra el siguiente error:

```
unknown attribute 'PzaXCja' for Producto.
Extracted source (around line #73):

      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      producto = find_by_Clave(row["Clave"]) || new
      producto.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*row.to_hash.keys) 
      producto.save!
    end
  end
```

Este es mi método en el modelo `producto`:

```
  has_one :productosxpza, class_name: "Productosxpza", foreign_key: "Producto"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :productosxpza

  def self.to_csv(options = {})#exportar
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.each do |producto|
        csv << producto.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end

  def self.import(file)#importar
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      producto = find_by_Clave(row["Clave"]) || new
      producto.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*row.to_hash.keys) #*row.to_hash.keys para rails 4 que sustituye el attr_accesible de rails 3
      producto.save!
    end
  end

  def self.open_spreadsheet(file)#importar
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
     when '.csv' then Roo::Csv.new(file.path, packed: false, file_warning: :ignore)
     #when '.xls' then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, packed: false, file_warning: :ignore)
     when '.xlsx' then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, packed: false, file_warning: :ignore)
     #else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
     else raise "El formato debe ser .xlsx ó .csv"


     end
  end
```

Comment: El título está mal. No estás usando Railscasts, estás usando Rails y la gema Roo. Estás siguiendo el tutorial de Railscast :)

Comment: Podrías decirme cuál es exactamente la línea 73? Es un poco difícil identificar el problema con lo que pones, pero me salta que esté intentando acceder a "PzaXCja" cuando lo que tienes es un "productosxpza"

Comment: No conozco la gema la verdad, pero puedes guardar en excel como csv y recorrerlo con ruby para guardo en tu base de datos. Te dejo un post que te puede ser útil https://www.sitepoint.com/guide-ruby-csv-library-part-2/